# maven release:perform failing to even try to generate javadoc or sources

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin, maven-source-plugin

Since moving to Java 11 quite a while ago now, the maven release plugin fails to generate javadoc alongside the built artifact.  My configuration for both in parent pom (and compiler plugin, in case relevant):

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <doclint>none</doclint>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
```

If I do mvn javadoc:javadoc, it works fine.
If I do mvn clean install -DperformRelease=true, it works fine (javadoc is generated alongside the main artifact).

But if I try to do a real build, with mvn release:prepare followed by mvn release:perform, I get no errors at all, in fact I get no indication that its even attempting to call the javadoc plugin.  The only artifact I get is the main JAR.

Here's the end of the output from mvn release:perform, after the tests all pass, when it would normally generate javadoc and sources and theh the maven-install-plugin would then install those too:

```
W:\test\momime-gitutilstest>mvn release:prepare
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.ndg.common:git-utils >----------------------
[INFO] Building ndgUtils 0.4.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M4:prepare (default-cli) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] phase verify-release-configuration
[INFO] starting prepare goal, composed of 17 phases: check-poms, scm-check-modifications, check-dependency-snapshots, create-backup-poms, map-release-versions, input-variables, map-development-versions, rewrite-poms-for-release, generate-release-poms, run-preparation-goals, scm-commit-release, scm-tag, rewrite-poms-for-development, remove-release-poms, run-completion-goals, scm-commit-development, end-release
[INFO] [prepare] 1/17 check-poms
[INFO] [prepare] 2/17 scm-check-modifications
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **\pom.xml.next, **\release.properties, **\pom.xml.branch, **\pom.xml.tag, **\pom.xml.backup, **\pom.xml.releaseBackup
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --show-prefix"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status --porcelain ."
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? release.properties
[INFO] [prepare] 3/17 check-dependency-snapshots
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
[INFO] [prepare] 4/17 create-backup-poms
[INFO] [prepare] 5/17 map-release-versions
What is the release version for "ndgUtils"? (com.ndg.common:git-utils) 0.4.5: :
[INFO] [prepare] 6/17 input-variables
What is the SCM release tag or label for "ndgUtils"? (com.ndg.common:git-utils) git-utils-0.4.5: :
[INFO] [prepare] 7/17 map-development-versions
What is the new development version for "ndgUtils"? (com.ndg.common:git-utils) 0.4.6-SNAPSHOT: :
[INFO] [prepare] 8/17 rewrite-poms-for-release
[INFO] Transforming 'ndgUtils'...
[INFO] [prepare] 9/17 generate-release-poms
[INFO] Not generating release POMs
[INFO] [prepare] 10/17 run-preparation-goals
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] ----------------------< com.ndg.common:git-utils >----------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building ndgUtils 0.4.5
[INFO] [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.14.0:generate (main-xjc-generate) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO] Sources are not up-to-date, XJC will be executed.
[INFO] WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
[INFO] WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (file:/W:/maven/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.0/jaxb-runtime-2.3.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
[INFO] WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
[INFO] WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
[INFO] WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] [INFO] Episode file [W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\generated-sources\xjc-layoutmanagers\META-INF\layoutmanagers.episode] was augmented with if-exists="true" attributes.
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'cp1252' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'cp1252' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] [INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] [INFO] Compiling 52 source files to W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\classes
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'cp1252' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'cp1252' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] [INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] [INFO] Compiling 20 source files to W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\test-classes
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.math.TestRomanNumerals
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.144 s - in com.ndg.math.TestRomanNumerals
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.swing.layoutmanagers.xmllayout.TestXmlLayoutContainerExImpl
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in com.ndg.swing.layoutmanagers.xmllayout.TestXmlLayoutContainerExImpl
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.swing.layoutmanagers.xmllayout.TestXmlLayoutManager
[INFO] Jul. 11, 2021 11:27:48 A.M. com.ndg.swing.layoutmanagers.xmllayout.XmlLayoutManager layoutContainer
[INFO] WARNING: No entry in XML layout was found for component with name "ButtonFour"
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.894 s - in com.ndg.swing.layoutmanagers.xmllayout.TestXmlLayoutManager
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.swing.TestJPanelWithConstantRepaints
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.07 s - in com.ndg.swing.TestJPanelWithConstantRepaints
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.swing.TestMouseClickListener
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.067 s - in com.ndg.swing.TestMouseClickListener
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.FileNameUtilsTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.044 s - in com.ndg.utils.FileNameUtilsTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.NumberUtilsTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in com.ndg.utils.NumberUtilsTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.ProcessUtilsImplTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in com.ndg.utils.ProcessUtilsImplTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.BooleanTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.017 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.BooleanTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.DelphiDateTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.DelphiDateTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.DoubleTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.DoubleTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.LengthAndStringTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.LengthAndStringTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.Signed2ByteShortTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.Signed2ByteShortTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.Signed4ByteIntTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.Signed4ByteIntTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.Signed8ByteLongTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.Signed8ByteLongTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.Unsigned2ByteIntTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.Unsigned2ByteIntTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.Unsigned4ByteLongTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.Unsigned4ByteLongTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.StringUtilsTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in com.ndg.utils.StringUtilsTest
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] Results:
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 49, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\git-utils-0.4.5.jar
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time:  22.750 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-11T11:28:04-02:30
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [prepare] 11/17 scm-commit-release
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --show-prefix"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status --porcelain ."
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? pom.xml.releaseBackup
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? release.properties
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? target/
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git commit --verbose -F C:\Users\NIGELG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-1323264089.commit"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git symbolic-ref HEAD"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push ssh:********@git.code.sf.net/p/momime/gitutilstest refs/heads/develop:refs/heads/develop"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] [prepare] 12/17 scm-tag
[INFO] Tagging release with the label git-utils-0.4.5...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git tag -F C:\Users\NIGELG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-79680122.commit git-utils-0.4.5"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push ssh:********@git.code.sf.net/p/momime/gitutilstest refs/tags/git-utils-0.4.5"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git ls-files"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] [prepare] 13/17 rewrite-poms-for-development
[INFO] Transforming 'ndgUtils'...
[INFO] [prepare] 14/17 remove-release-poms
[INFO] Not removing release POMs
[INFO] [prepare] 15/17 run-completion-goals
[INFO] [prepare] 16/17 scm-commit-development
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --show-prefix"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status --porcelain ."
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? pom.xml.releaseBackup
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? release.properties
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? target/
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git commit --verbose -F C:\Users\NIGELG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-2027775157.commit"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git symbolic-ref HEAD"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push ssh:********@git.code.sf.net/p/momime/gitutilstest refs/heads/develop:refs/heads/develop"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest
[INFO] [prepare] 17/17 end-release
[INFO] Release preparation complete.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  49.197 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-11T11:28:14-02:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

















W:\test\momime-gitutilstest>mvn release:perform
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.ndg.common:git-utils >----------------------
[INFO] Building ndgUtils 0.4.6-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M4:perform (default-cli) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] phase verify-release-configuration
[INFO] starting perform goal, composed of 3 phases: verify-completed-prepare-phases, checkout-project-from-scm, run-perform-goals
[INFO] [perform] 1/3 verify-completed-prepare-phases
[INFO] [perform] 2/3 checkout-project-from-scm
[INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git clone --depth 1 --branch git-utils-0.4.5 ssh:********@git.code.sf.net/p/momime/gitutilstest checkout"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git ls-remote ssh:********@git.code.sf.net/p/momime/gitutilstest"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\NIGELG~1\AppData\Local\Temp
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git fetch ssh:********@git.code.sf.net/p/momime/gitutilstest"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\checkout
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git checkout git-utils-0.4.5"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\checkout
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git ls-files"
[INFO] Working directory: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\checkout
[INFO] [perform] 3/3 run-perform-goals
[INFO] Invoking perform goals in directory W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\checkout
[INFO] Executing goals 'deploy'...
[INFO] pomFileName is already set, ignoring the -f argument
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] ----------------------< com.ndg.common:git-utils >----------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building ndgUtils 0.4.5
[INFO] [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.14.0:generate (main-xjc-generate) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO] Sources are not up-to-date, XJC will be executed.
[INFO] WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
[INFO] WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (file:/W:/maven/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.0/jaxb-runtime-2.3.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
[INFO] WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
[INFO] WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
[INFO] WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] [INFO] Episode file [W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\checkout\target\generated-sources\xjc-layoutmanagers\META-INF\layoutmanagers.episode] was augmented with if-exists="true" attributes.
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'cp1252' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'cp1252' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] [INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] [INFO] Compiling 52 source files to W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\checkout\target\classes
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'cp1252' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'cp1252' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] [INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] [INFO] Compiling 20 source files to W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\checkout\target\test-classes
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.math.TestRomanNumerals
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.17 s - in com.ndg.math.TestRomanNumerals
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.swing.layoutmanagers.xmllayout.TestXmlLayoutContainerExImpl
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in com.ndg.swing.layoutmanagers.xmllayout.TestXmlLayoutContainerExImpl
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.swing.layoutmanagers.xmllayout.TestXmlLayoutManager
[INFO] Jul. 11, 2021 11:28:39 A.M. com.ndg.swing.layoutmanagers.xmllayout.XmlLayoutManager layoutContainer
[INFO] WARNING: No entry in XML layout was found for component with name "ButtonFour"
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.954 s - in com.ndg.swing.layoutmanagers.xmllayout.TestXmlLayoutManager
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.swing.TestJPanelWithConstantRepaints
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.054 s - in com.ndg.swing.TestJPanelWithConstantRepaints
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.swing.TestMouseClickListener
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.043 s - in com.ndg.swing.TestMouseClickListener
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.FileNameUtilsTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.049 s - in com.ndg.utils.FileNameUtilsTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.NumberUtilsTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in com.ndg.utils.NumberUtilsTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.ProcessUtilsImplTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in com.ndg.utils.ProcessUtilsImplTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.BooleanTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.012 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.BooleanTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.DelphiDateTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.DelphiDateTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.DoubleTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.DoubleTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.LengthAndStringTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.LengthAndStringTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.Signed2ByteShortTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.Signed2ByteShortTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.Signed4ByteIntTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.Signed4ByteIntTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.Signed8ByteLongTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.Signed8ByteLongTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.Unsigned2ByteIntTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.Unsigned2ByteIntTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.stream.Unsigned4ByteLongTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in com.ndg.utils.stream.Unsigned4ByteLongTest
[INFO] [INFO] Running com.ndg.utils.StringUtilsTest
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in com.ndg.utils.StringUtilsTest
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] Results:
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] Tests run: 49, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\checkout\target\git-utils-0.4.5.jar
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install (default-install) @ git-utils ---
[INFO] [INFO] Installing W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\checkout\target\git-utils-0.4.5.jar to W:\maven\repository\com\ndg\common\git-utils\0.4.5\git-utils-0.4.5.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Installing W:\test\momime-gitutilstest\target\checkout\pom.xml to W:\maven\repository\com\ndg\common\git-utils\0.4.5\git-utils-0.4.5.pom
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy (default-deploy) @ git-utils ---
```

Have searched around endlessly for a solution to this, but most posts are either a) people with javadoc generation failing because they do not have doclint=none, or b) people wanting to turn javadoc generation completely.  I cannot find anything about how to turn it ON, since it should be on by default.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks.

(Edit: added parent pom config and SO tag for maven-source-plugin too since that has exactly the same problem in that it just fails to run)

Comment: And what error are happening? I don't see any error here in the post?

Comment: There is no error message, that's the problem.  The javadoc plugin just fails to execute.  If I had an error message I would at leave have some lead or direction on what to try.

Comment: A whole log file would be helpful...

Comment: Done, was trying to only post relevant info, but included the whole log now (up until the point that the deploy plugin fails as I have no nexus repo to deploy to, but that's expected and I always had that even when javadoc+sources were working).

Comment: I have somewhat of an answer.  If do "mvn release:perform -DuseReleaseProfile=true" then it works as expected.  But when did this extra param become necessary and why?  Maven release plugin docs say useReleaseProfile defaults to false, but it must have defaulted to true at some point in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching and trying things which did not work, ended up tracking it down to this setting which must be added.  Though I am still puzzled that this worked fine in the past without this, so they must have changed the default from true to false.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useReleaseProfile>true</useReleaseProfile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Update: yes checked back versions of the release plugin - in 3.0.0-M4 useReleaseProfile defaults to true, in 2.5.3 (latest 2.x.x) it defaulted to false.

Answer (score 0):

This guide helps: [migration guide release plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/migrate.html)

Following that you can just do mvn release:prepare/mvn release:perform